# Why do singular matrices have no inverse?

Tags: matrices, determinant

I know that if $A$ is a square matrix of order $n$ , then  :

$$A*\mathbb{adj}(A)=|A|I_n\cdots(1)$$

where $I_n$ is identity matrix of order $n$.

By definition of inverse of matrix ( which is $AA^{-1}=I$) , and also the fact that inverse must be unique , I can deduce from equation $1$ that :

$$A^{-1}= \frac{\mathbb{adj}(A)}{|A|}$$

given that $|A| ≠0$
This is because, it's valid to divide both side by a non-zero number , here which is $|A|$ .

Now , if $|A|=0$ , we cannot divide both side by zero , hence the only thing I get is :

$$A*\mathbb{adj}(A)={O}$$

But I cannot deduce from this equation that why an inverse can not exist. My teacher said that it's because if determinant is zero , then we cannot divide both side by zero , hence we can't get our inverse. But how can I ensure that there isn't any other method or equation through which I can obtain the inverse ? In other words, how can I ensure that the equation $1$ above in this post is the only way to obtain an inverse , so that If I can't get the inverse from equation $1$ , then I can't get it from anywhere else ? So my question is :

**How to prove that a singular matrix have no inverse**?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For square matrices, it holds that $\det AB = \det A \cdot \det B$. If $A$ was singular and had an inverse $A^{-1}$, then $0=\det A\det A^{-1}=\det E = 1$.

---

More generally, if one of the terms is singular, then the product is also singular.

Comment: It's so obvious but I couldn't observe this. Thanks very much. Also , I think it should be $I$ instead of $E$ .

Comment: I am used to writing $E$ for the identity. You may use whatever notation you prefer.

Comment: Now the question is why does 0 determinant mean non-invertible and why is the determinant multiplicative?

Comment: @qwr Zero determinant means matrix has no inverse as shown above and distribution of determinant can be proved using elementary operations or otherwise

Answer (score 1):

The idea of an inverse is to "cancel" a prior operation and to "recover" the original vector. Consider $A^{-1}Ax = Ix = x$. First, $Ax$ project $x$ to the row vector space of $A$ and let's call the resulting vector $y$. If $A$ is not of full rank, you will "lose information" on some dimensions of $x$ (because rows of A does not form the basis for the full-rank vector space), which means there exist many $x$s that project to the same $y$. This is similar to the concept of a non injective function. Now, you want to recover $x$ from $y$ (by defining an inverse operation $A^{-1}$), but there is no way to find a unique preimage $x$ to recover to, so $A^{-1}$ does not exist.

Comment: Thanks. Though unfortunately I don't know the relation between matrices and vectors as well as ranks :(